# Customizing Swarm Connect leaderboard

Tags: java, android, leaderboard

Right now I am displaying a `SwarmConnect` online leaderboard this way:

```
public void showLeaderboard() {
    SwarmLeaderboard.showLeaderboard(LEADERBOARD_ID);
}
```

And it displays the below leaderboard:

[image]

This is obviously formatted and looks like `SwarmConnect` and looks nothing like my app during gameplay.  Is there any way to customize this leaderboard such as just pulling the values and putting it in a high scores table that I create myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, not as easy, but possible
they give a good example on their page

Check it out here. http://swarmconnect.com/admin/docs/kissthefish

Comment: Ugh, never saw this when navigating through their site.  Thanks!